# BAD USB Atmega32u4 - Problem with performing various activities on one USB

Tags: if-statement, arduino, atmega, arduino-c++

I have a problem with the Atmega32u4 board. I'm creating a program on BadUSB, which, according to assumptions, should do 3 different things. The problem is that in between these activities the computer shuts down. My idea was a simple counter with if statements, but the board doesn't save the current state permanently. I was thinking about detecting the situation he is currently in, but I have no idea how to do it. Could you please help me?

**Functionality 1** - locked computer, opening CMD, entering the command.

*Turning off the computer*

**Functionality 2** - unlocked computer, opening CMD, entering the command.

*Logging out of the account/unplugging the USB.*

**Functionality 3** - locked computer, opening CMD, entering the command.

Do you have any ideas how to detect these situations? Or possibly how to save the counter state "permanently"

I made something like this:

```
 int i = 0;

  if (i == 0){

//Opening CMD

  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press('r');
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);

  Keyboard.print("cmd.exe");
  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);

//First functionality

  Keyboard.print("echo Task 1");
  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);

  i++;

  return;
  }
  
  else if (i == 1){

//Opening CMD

  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press('r');
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);


  Keyboard.print("cmd.exe");
  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);

//Second functionality

  Keyboard.print("echo Task 2");
  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(1000);


  i++;
  return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATmega32U4 has a 1 kB builtin EEPROM (See Datasheeet [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf)). You can use that to store a persistent state when the chip is turned off. You tagged your question as Arduino, so here is a [guide](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/eeprom) to using EEPROM with Arduino Libraries.